# Determine mouse hover position on progress bar?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to determine the position of the mouse when it hovers over a HTML progress bar? For example, if I'm using a progress bar while playing an audio file, I want to have a tool tip appear when the user moves the mouse over the progress bar that shows the timestamp in the audio where they are hovering. This would be a way to preview the location of the track they would be seeking to before they clicked on it.

Comment: Have a look to [**`hover()`**](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp).

Comment: *Is it possible to determine the position of the mouse when it hovers over a HTML progress bar?* <-- Yes.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the `mouseenter` event on the element.

```
document.getElementById("progress").addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) {
})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter

the event gives you some futher properties like `clientX` and `clientY`.
When combining those with the position of the progress bar and some subtraction you should be able to determine the position of the mouse within the progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the direction. The 'mousemove' event is what I was looking for.

I modified some code from a similar answer on this site to use that event:

```
document.getElementById('progressBar').addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;

    //Convert x value to progress range [0 1]
    var xconvert = x/300; //300 is width of the progress bar
    var finalx = (xconvert).toFixed(2);

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = ('Hover position: ' + finalx + "<br/>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2dqn5brs/